# Slide box horizontally in jQuery with animate

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-animate

I want to slide a div left and right with animate in jQuery.
So far I have the below conatined in [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/aaronk85/7urNX/).

The problem is that each time I am clicking left or right my variable left is going back to the original position onload rather than its current position.  What am i doing wrong here? I want it to go left on each click or right on each click from where it currently is.

```
    <div id="yellowbox"></div>
    <div id="left">left</div>
    <div id="right">right</div>


    <script>
        var left = $('#yellowbox').offset().left;
        console.log(left);

        jQuery(document).on('click', '#left', function(event) {
            $("#yellowbox").css({left:left}).animate({"left": (left -50)}, "slow");
        });

        jQuery(document).on('click', '#right', function(event) {
            $("#yellowbox").css({left:left}).animate({"left": (left +50)}, "slow");
        });
    </script>

    <style>     
    #yellowbox {
        width: 50px;
        height: 50px;
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        right: 550px;
        background: yellow;
    }
    </style>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should remove the call to `.css`, without it the code works fine. Because, the `.css` modifies the position directly with no effects and then animation takes place.

### <kbd>[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/GaurangTandon/7urNX/2/)</kbd>

```
var left = $('#yellowbox').offset().left;


$(document).on('click', '#left', function(event) {
    left -= 50;   // you were not modifying the variable here
    $("#yellowbox").animate({
        "left": left 
    }, "slow");
});

$(document).on('click', '#right', function(event) {
    left += 50;  // you were not modifying the variable here
    $("#yellowbox").animate({
        "left": left
    }, "slow");
});
```

Comment: thanks, sorry I am not sure if I described it clearly, on each click I want it to continue to move left/right

Comment: thanks, I will except, altough it might be more useful for others if we add in something to stop scrolling when it goes off the screen?  I have added it in in this fiddle, http://jsfiddle.net/aaronk85/7urNX/3/ did you want to update your answer? (you will probably have a better way than what I did)

Comment: @ak85 Well Done! Good to see the progress :) and for updating my answer, no, I won't as it's your work. Just some suggestions though: 1) You can store the limit for the screen in a variable to use later, as your if condition computes it every time button is pressed, resulting heavy memory usage. 2) Update the limit variable every time window is resized using $(window).resize (google!), and thus eliminate the `width` and `boxWidth`` vairiables also. Else, very well done :D

Comment: [Here's that thing I just created it.](http://jsfiddle.net/GaurangTandon/7urNX/4/)

Answer (score 1):

You need to assign your "left" variable on every call:-

```
var left = $('#yellowbox').offset().left;

    jQuery(document).on('click', '#left', function(event) {
        left = $('#yellowbox').offset().left;

        $("#yellowbox").css({left:left}).animate({"left": (left -50)}, "slow");
    });

    jQuery(document).on('click', '#right', function(event) {
       left = $('#yellowbox').offset().left;

        $("#yellowbox").css({left:left}).animate({"left": (left +50)}, "slow");
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

On every click you need to save the left variable:

```
var left = $('#yellowbox').offset().left;
console.log(left);

jQuery(document).on('click', '#left', function(event) {
    $("#yellowbox").css({left:left}).animate({"left": (left -50)}, "slow");
    left = $('#yellowbox').offset().left -50;
});

jQuery(document).on('click', '#right', function(event) {
    $("#yellowbox").css({left:left}).animate({"left": (left +50)}, "slow");
    left = $('#yellowbox').offset().left + 50;
});
```